# What should I learn beforehand to understand Jordan B Peterson's view on symbolism?

Tags: skepticism, jordan-peterson

To begin to Understand Peterson's View on Symbolism and it's manifestation and representation, what prior works are recommended to read/review that either serve as the basis for his conjectures, or that directly serve to challenge/contradict them?
Or should I just go through all of his writings/works and then try to establish clarification and skepticism from there?

I was wondering if someone familiar with his work or who has already gone through it could shed some insight.

Comment: You might enjoy this critique from an academic specialist in mythology: 'Jordan Peterson Does Not Understand Mythology', Spencer McDaniel https://talesoftimesforgotten.com/2021/04/05/jordan-peterson-does-not-understand-mythology/ Gives a good run-down of the sources he relies on.

Comment: Thank you all! I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: It depends: What do you mean by "Jordan" ? what do you mean by "B" ? What do you mean by "Peterson" ?

Comment: Nietzsche, Jung for the symbolism-psychology connection, Dostoyevski who's more Christian. And most important **The Bible**. This last is most important. Many hundreds of thousands now number as JBP's fans today. Many of them start reading the Bible **through him**. This is clearly (to me!) better than not reading the Bible. But I'd humbly suggest that it's not optimal. It's better to get a simplified lay of the land on *other* more first order basis — Jesus said this, Adam did that. And then delve into JBP symbolism. Then u can choose on your own his critics (the other comments) side or fans

Comment: Personally I like the older JBP better. When he was more psychological, more symbolical, more tentative in his Christian commitment. Now he's too much a charismatic Christian + unabashed right winger for my taste. Personally (as a non Christian) it's important to be an agnostic to be religious. See [Carl Sagan](https://youtu.be/Ugyrzr5Ds8o). When you're cocksure you're not religious. Perhaps the situation is [so much worse](https://youtu.be/9fxD3QUzARw) now that taking a hard side is increasingly needed and inevitable

Comment: start with zizek!